# jQuery Toggle Show / Hide Form Inside HTML Table

Tags: jquery

I have this Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2nAEZ/3/

the idea is very simple... when the page shows up all elements inside  tags are hidden. except "Reply" button.

once "Reply" button clicked, the form appear with "Cancel" button.

but, how to make "Reply" button works on each row? not all forms show up when a Reply button clicked. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2nAEZ/17/)**. I cleaned up your HTML (no dupe IDs) and changed the jQuery to operate on a per-row basis.

**jQuery**

```
$("form, .hide").hide();
$(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find("form,.hide").show();
    $(this).parents('tr').find(".show").hide();
});
$(".hide").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find("form, .hide").hide();
    $(this).parents('tr').find(".show").show();
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<table><tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>message here<br>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Send">
        </form></td>
    <td>
        <button class="hide">Cancel</button>
        <button class="show">Reply</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>67890</td>
    <td>another message here<br>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Send">
        </form></td>
    <td>
        <button class="hide">Cancel</button>
        <button class="show">Reply</button>
    </td>
</tr></table>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same IDs! Since your forms are generated by PHP,

```
<button class="hide" data-form="<?=$form_number?>">Cancel</button>
<button class="show" data-form="<?=$form_number?>">Reply</button>
```

then,

```
$("form, .hide").hide();
$(".show").click(function(){
   formnum = $(this).data("form");
   $("form"+formnum+", .hide").show();
   $('.show[data-form="'+formnum+'"').hide();
});

$(".hide").click(function(){
   formnum = $(this).data("form");
   $("form"+formnum+", .hide").hide();
   $('.show[data-form="'+formnum+'"').show();
});
```

You can have multiple elements with the same class.

Comment: bro, still when I click a Reply button, both forms appear. that's the problem. how to make a form associates with Reply button which only appear?

Comment: Yeah, i realised that, give me a minute

Comment: dynamically generated with PHP

Comment: Try this now, edited the code, where `$form_number` is the current no. of the form PHP is printing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control each one independently you might want to do this:

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form, #hide").hide();

    $("#show1").click(function(){
    $("#form1, #hide1").show();
    $("#show1").hide();
    });

    $("#hide1").click(function(){
    $("#form1, #hide1").hide();
    $("#show1").show();
    });
});​
```

html:

```
<tr>
    <td>12345</td>
    <td>message here<br>
        <form id="form1" action=\"\" method=\"post\">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input id="reply1" type="button" value="Send">
        </form></td>
    <td>
        <button id="hide1">Cancel</button>
        <button id="show1">Reply</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
    <td>67890</td>
    <td>another message here<br>
        <form id="form2" action=\"\" method=\"post\">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <input id="reply2" type="button" value="Send">
        </form></td>
    <td>
        <button id="hide2">Cancel</button>
        <button id="show2">Reply</button>
    </td>
</tr>​
```

You will need additional js to control the second form.

Comment: j08691's answer is cleaner than this.  Go with that.